# How does this oscillator circuit works?

Tags: transistors, capacitor, inductor, oscillator, npn

[image]

When the switch is closed, the current flows through the resistor and because of it high amount of current flows through lower portion of the coil and led turn on. In the meantime, because of the electromagnetic induction counter emf is generated in the upper portion of the coil meaning the capacitor starts to charge through the upper portion of coil.

So the positive voltage is developed in the upper plate of the capacitor which means a negative voltage is also developed in lower plate of the capacitor. when that negative voltage is higher than the base-emitter threshold voltage the transistor stops conducting and no current flow lower portion of coil and led stop glowing.

Now the capacitor will start discharging through the upper plate of capacitor and upper portion of coil and resistor. because of it lower portion of the capacitor becomes less and less negative and at a certain point, the voltage of the lower plate of the capacitor will be less negative than base- emitter voltage and the transistor starts conducting and the led glows again.

this is my understanding of this circuit am I right or wrong? correct me please